# App Script HTML Service Calling CSS File showing as Plain Text

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script, web-applications

I am trying to get my css.html file to be brought into my index.html and am using a html service to call the css file. Simple enough but I cannot seem to get the function to be seen as anything other than text. In the inspect tool it shows it as appearing in the body even though I am placing it in the header. Am I missing something with formatting or maybe it's a page loading issue?

```
<head>
<base target="_top">

<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('css').getContent(); ?>

</head>
```

[image]

Comment: Please add a [mcve]. You should add the sample content for the css.html file and show the doGet fuction.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

You need to create a template and then use evaluate() method

```
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

<?!= include('css') ?>
```

Comment: I am sure this will work but the problem I am having with your recommendation or otherwise is that <?!= include('css') ?> keeps shows as a string of text in the body so I can't even get to the point in which the function is being called.

Comment: Please show how you created the template.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it working. I was using `.createHtmlOutputFromFile()` to create the HTML but it looks like I needed to create a template for the index and then create the CSS as HTML.

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate();
}

    function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
```